# Why isn't my checkbox or radiobutton showing on the website?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Every time that I place an asp radio button or checkbox none show in the website, which is strange because it shows in the design mode. Any suggestions?
Is it the css?

Tried to make them visible on the page load still couldn't make it work.

```html
<form method="post" action="#" runat="server">
    <div class="row">
        <!--EMAIL-->
        <div class="col-6 col-12-mobile">
            <asp:TextBox ID="dfEmail" placeholder="Email" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </div>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" Style="color: red" runat="server" ErrorMessage="* Campo por preencher!" ControlToValidate="dfEmail"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

        <!--TELEFONE-->
        <div class="col-6 col-12-mobile">
            <asp:TextBox ID="dfTelefone" placeholder="Telefone" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </div>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" Style="color: red" runat="server" ErrorMessage="* Campo por preencher!" ControlToValidate="dfTelefone"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

        <!--MORADA-->
        <div class="col-6 col-12-mobile">
            <asp:TextBox ID="dfMorada" placeholder="Morada" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </div>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" Style="color: red" runat="server" ErrorMessage="* Campo por preencher!" ControlToValidate="dfMorada"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        
        <div class="col-6 col-12-mobile"><asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton1" Text="Deseja Mudar a Password?" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="RadioButton1_CheckedChanged" /></div>

        <!--MUDAR PASSWORD-->
        <div class="col-6 col-12-mobile">
            <asp:TextBox ID="dfPassword" placeholder="Password" Textmode="Password" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </div>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator4" Style="color: red" runat="server" ErrorMessage="* Campo por preencher!" ControlToValidate="dfPassword"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

        <!--CONFIRMAR MUDAR PASSWORD-->
        <div class="col-6 col-12-mobile">
            <asp:TextBox ID="dfPasswordConf" placeholder="Confirmar Password" Textmode="Password" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </div>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator5" Style="color: red" runat="server" ErrorMessage="* Campo por preencher!" ControlToValidate="dfPasswordConf"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

        <!--FAZER ALTERAÇÕES-->
        <div class="col-12">
            <asp:Button ID="btnSubmeterAlteracoes" runat="server" Text="Submeter Alterações" OnClick="btnSubmeterAlteracoes_Click" />
        </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

[image: img1]

[image: img2]

Comment: `View Source` in the web browser. Is it in the HTML?

Comment: This? https://imgur.com/a/KkVfFEI

Comment: Did you check the CSS? Any obvious reason why it would be hidden?